# OWL class get equivalent classes

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I'm trying to get all equivalent classes of an OWL class. I'm using this code but it doesn't work, it returns either empty brackets or the IRI class (I mean the IRI of cls).

I want to get the equivalent classes because I need to mention them as super classes of the given class (in the example the class cls ). So, If cls class is equivalent to the intersection of some other classes, then all those classes are super classes of cls class.

```
  public static Set<OWLClass> getEquivalentClasses(OWLClassExpression cls) {

        Node<OWLClass> equivalentClasses = reasoner.getEquivalentClasses(cls);
        Set<OWLClass> result = null;
        if (cls.isAnonymous()) {
            result = equivalentClasses.getEntities();
        } else {
            result = equivalentClasses.getEntitiesMinus(cls.asOWLClass());
        }
        return result;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, which reasoner are you using, and what are the contents of the ontology?

Comment: Hello, I use HermiT reasoner. For the ontology, I use the standard one given by protogé "people.owl"

Comment: This an excerpt of the ontology showing the three equivalent classes for the class "man"   :

Comment: <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleee#man">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class>  <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleee#adult"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleee#person"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleee#male"/>
        </owl:intersectionOf>   </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">man</rdfs:label></owl:Class>

Comment: That equivalent class axiom has only anonymous classes apart from man. OWLReasoner implementations never return anonymous classes as part of a node. That's why you're not seeing any class. Try adding an equivalent named class, e.g., hombre, to the axiom, and see if it gets returned.

Comment: Right, the reasoner is quite obvious, there infinite man ycomplex  equivalent class. You can also just the ontology, i.e. the asserted axioms,see the `EntitySearcher` class:  http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/search/EntitySearcher.html#getEquivalentClasses-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology-

Comment: Hello, I found another alternative without using the reasoner: TheOntologyClass.getEquivalentClasses(TheOntology) it returns the equivalent classes